# Without using OOPS concept

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I am building apps in iOS  , can I build **mobile apps** in   iOS  using only structs to parse data from the web?

Comment: what is the problem OOPs ?. did you find any bad practice with OOPs? . if so what is that ?

Comment: Up voted both the answer and the above comment. Bottom line is - what's the specific issue? OOP versus "top-down"? Protocols? Using Xcode's way of implementing OOP? While I'm surprised @rmaddy's answer is uprooted so much, I'm more surprised your question isn't down voted too much. Please, this site is about specifics - what exactly is wrong with *can I build **mobile apps** in iOS without using OOP*?

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, no, you can't. And iOS app is built on many required frameworks such as UIKit. Things like view, label, view controller, table views, etc. are all using object oriented classes.

Even the basics of Swift start off with classes. Use a string, you've created an instance of a class. Use an integer, you've created an instance of a class. OK, technically both of those are actually structures but it is still object oriented.

You simply can't avoid OOP when writing an iOS app in a language like Swift or Objective-C. Accept the fact that you need to become familiar and comfortable with those concepts.

Start with the [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book and you will be introduced to the concepts as you learn.